# Tracing input & output of message channels of Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-integration

I have build a small application using Spring Integration. I have also written some jUnit for more service and other classes. 
I have used XML configuration for the channel and en-point configuration, I am wondering if I can test the input and output of a perticular channel.
Is there a way we can test the input and output of the channels?..

**Update**

I am trying to the below flow. How shall i proceed?

```
<int:channel id="getPresciption" />
<int:channel id="respPrescription" />
<int:channel id="storePrcedureChannell" />

<int-http:inbound-gateway
    request-channel="getPresciption" reply-channel="respPrescription"
    supported-methods="GET" path="/getAllPresciption">

    <int-http:request-mapping
        consumes="application/json" produces="application/json" />
</int-http:inbound-gateway>

<int:service-activator
    ref="prescriptionServiceActivator" method="buildPrescription"
    input-channel="getPresciption" output-channel="storePrcedureChannell" />

<int:service-activator
    ref="prescriptionServiceActivator" method="storePrescription"
    input-channel="storePrcedureChannell"></int:service-activator>
```

SO how can i write the Test contex?

Let below are the methods which are called by channel flow.

```
public Message<List<Prescription>> buildPrescription() {
  //Do some processing
}

public Message<List<Prescription>> storePrescription(Message<List<Prescription>> msg) {

  //Do something and return the List.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can take a look into the Spring Integration Testing Framework: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/testing.html#test-context

And then use a `MockIntegration.mockMessageHandler()` together with the `MockIntegrationContext.substituteMessageHandlerFor()` to replace a real handler in the endpoint and verify incoming data from the channel.

If that is still hard for you, you always can inject those channels into your test class and add to them a `ChannelInterceptor` and verify messages in its `preSend()` implementation.

Comment: I was expecting a reply from you Bilan. Few days back I saw your Gut repository code where you have done unit testing for spring Integration. I was something for testing channels as well. It that the way I have to proceed?.

Comment: Good. Does it help? Can you accept the answer already? Or do you have something else in doubts?

Comment: I will write some test cases and will post here

Comment: Yes those are helpful. I am following those. Let's see if I can do it without any problems.

Comment: I was following this link. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/testing-examples/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/testing

Do we haave to create xml for testing of each channel?
I have to write the test case for the flow in the Updated part.

Comment: i tried but not able to figure out how to proceed. If i get example for above, it will help me a lot in understanding.